# Can any matrix be reduced to RREF?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are all matrices able to be whittled down to RREF? If it doesn't, what are the requirements for it to be able?

Comment: When your book introduces RREF, does it mention any such limitations? Because if it's a decent book and there are limitations, then it ought to mention them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any matrix can be put into RREF. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form

Also, for any given matrix, there is only one RREF.